# Adding a dependency to all uses of an implicit rule

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile where I'm fine with existing `%.c` to `%.o` for compiling C files to object files.

However, I'd like that all `.o` files built using this implicit rule also depend on an additional header, `foo.h`.

I know I can add additional *one-off* rules to make individual `.o` files depend on `foo.h`, like:

```
bar.o : foo.h
```

... but I want to add `foo.h` as a dependency of *all* `.o` files generated from `.c` files.

Analogously with the above I tried this:

```
%.o : %.c foo.h
```

and this:

```
%.o : foo.h
```

to see if I could "add" the dependency but keep the implicit rule.

It didn't work. I can certainly just copy-paste the recipe from the implicit rule into my pattern rule like:

```
%.o : %.c foo.h
    $(CC) -c $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $<
```

But I'd like not to duplicate it if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your difficulty is due to how make handles pattern rules. To force make to consider `foo.h` as a prerequisite of all object files, you must explicitly list the object files, not rely on a pattern rule. But make offers a way to do this: the static pattern rule, which looks like a pattern rule but is more like a compact form of a set of similar regular rules. Example:

```
OBJS    := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard *.c))

$(OBJS): %.o: foo.h
```

The only constraint is that you must find a way to enumerate all your object files. This is frequently not a real problem.

Note that, in your specific case, the *pattern* feature is not even needed because the prerequisite is the same for all targets. You could also use:

```
OBJS    := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard *.c))

$(OBJS): foo.h
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess this is about on-par with duplicating the implicit rule.

Comment: @BeeOnRope I think it is related with the [Implicit Rule Search Algorithm](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Rule-Search). See step 4...

Comment: Quoting the manual: "They are more general than ordinary rules with multiple targets because the targets do not have to have identical prerequisites." ... but as the prerequisite in this case IS identical, I see no advantage using the static pattern rule over the normal `$(OBJS): foo.h`. Do I miss something?

Comment: @Vroomfondel You are right, in this case it is equivalent to the standard non-pattern rule. I mentioned the static pattern rule because the original was also based on a pattern and because static pattern rules are good to know. Edited my answer to include your remark.